# Add variable space at the end of line in file

Tags: sed, awk, echo

I want to add white space at the end of each line. Number of white space is in variable. If number of white space is fixed then I can use this command

```
sed 's/$/  /g'
```

for two spaces.

```
space_variable=4;
```

But if number of white space is variable (space_variable=4) then how can I use it?

Comment: Where is the variable defined? Script?

Answer (score 1):

```
spaces=$(printf "%*s" "$space_variable" "")
```

That will return the empty string *padded with spaces* to a field N characters wide.

Then: `sed "s/\$/$spaces/"`

In bash, you can use the builtin

```
printf -v spaces "%*s" "$space_variable" ""
```

but I find this less readable as it hides the variable name somewhat.